# What's the best way to pass variables/strings around between functions in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, variables, format

I have a lot of functions that have elements that need to communicate between themselves, but I'm having a dilemma on how to format this for most efficiency. Below I have a few examples of ways I've tried approaching this (**the code is just an example**)

```
fruits = "banana", "apple", "orange"
vegetable = "cucumber", "pepper", "onion"
first_name = "John"
```

**First Approach:** Here I've fed the function all the variables and it executes 3 tasks under 1 function. It gets the job done, but maybe I want to segment the tasks, so that it doesn't get too overwhelming to navigate if the code is bigger.

```
def preferences(first_name, last_name, what_he_likes, what_he_hates):
    full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
    
    for item in what_he_likes:
        print(full_name + " likes " + item)
        
    for item in what_he_hates:
        print(full_name + " hates " + item)
    
preferences(first_name, "Lambert", fruits, vegetable)
```

**Second Approach:** Here I have 3 separate functions, each with their own purpose. I like it because it's clearer, but I have to pass in the name every time. Now here it's fine, but you can imagine for a larger code maybe I'd have 3-4 variables that I'd need to pass into each of those functions.

```
def add_last_name(first_name, last_name):
    full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
    return full_name

def likes(name, what_he_likes):
    for item in what_he_likes:
        print(name + " likes " + item)

def hates(name, what_he_hates):
    for item in what_he_hates:
        print(name + " hates " + item)


full_name = add_last_name(first_name, "Lambert")
likes(full_name, fruits)
hates(full_name, vegetable)
```

**Third Approach:** In this example, it's all under one function, but maybe if I know that the name will always be the same, I can enter the string directly instead of having to pass variables around. But when I do this I always have this fear that entering strings directly is a destructive way to work because if I need to change it I'd have to dig through the code to do so.

```
def preferences_direct_name(what_he_likes, what_he_hates):
    for item in what_he_likes:
        print("John Lambert" + " likes " + item)
        
    for item in what_he_hates:
        print("John Lambert" + " hates " + item)
    
preferences_direct_name(fruits, vegetable)
```

I guess I'm wondering how do you guys prefer to structure your code. I sometimes find myself needing to return 1 variable to use in a different function only once, and I wonder should I just pass the string in that function directly so that I don't have to keep cluttering up the lines by returning all these variables and passing them as arguments.
On the other hand if I have 1 big function that encapsulates all the code, I won't have to do that but the code will be long with poor clarity.
I tried my best to explain, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on what you are trying to do. For me, I think the first approach is the cleanest one, and if you think the code will be too long or clattered, just add comments on each segment of the code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you

```
def preferences(first_name, last_name, what_he_likes, what_he_hates):
    full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"    
    for item in what_he_likes + what_he_hates:
        category = "likes" if item in what_he_likes else "hates"
        print(f"{full_name} {category} {item}")
#sample
first_name = "John"
preferences(first_name, "Lambert", ["fruits", "movies"], ["vegetables", "rain"])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The decision of best way to pass variable between function is influenced by a number of elements, readability, maintainability, and the particular requirements of your project.

Every method you described has specific applications, and the most appropriate method may change based on the circumstance (your team coding style, project requirement, ...).